# Does Javascript has a function like FindControlRecursive?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Each row of a ListView has a checkbox. When the user clicks **Delete Selected row(s)** LinkButton,  only rows that have the checkbox checked are deleted. I'm thinking about getting all the checkboxes in an array first then loop through to see which one was checked.

This is what I have tried.

```
    function CheckBoxBeforeDeleteing() {
        var lv = document.getElementById("MainContent_ListView1");
        //var inputs = lv.childNodes;
        //alert(inputs.Length);
        alert("Test");
    }
```

If I don't comment out the 2 lines, the function is not even executed. It looks like I need to go deeper. Does Javascript has something function like the C#'s **FindControlRecursive**?

Comment: Maybe it's not working because `lv` is `null`; that is, because there's no element on the page whose id is "MainContent_ListView1". Have you done any debugging at all? Did you get errors in the console?

Comment: add a CSS class to the checkbox control and look for that instead (getelementsbyclass) (sorry I'm on mobile right now) - IDs change when rendered with C# but classes dont

Comment: and Length should not start with an uppercase L

Comment: There's no `getELementsByClassName()` in IE until IE9.

Comment: @Pointy wow I actually didn't know that. Thanks. Well you can still get the elements by attribute, right?

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel well there's `getElementsByTagName()`, and you can of course directly iterate over the DOM via the "childNodes" lists.

Comment: @Pointy wow I've been using jQuery so long I forgot about all this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through the elements in the forms using loop in javascript as give below. Suppose you have `form1` in your page with `runat="server"` then get the form and iterate through its controls using loop and find the checkboxes within form.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('<%= form1.ClientID %>').elements;

function CheckBoxBeforeDeleteing() 
{
    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
    {
          if(elem[i].id.indexOf('chkBoxId') != -1)
          {
               if(elem[i].checked)
               {
                     //Your code here
               }
          }   
    }
}
```

**Accessing form with index**

```
function CheckBoxBeforeDeleteing() 
{
    for(i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)
    {
          e=document.forms[0].elements[i];
          if (e.id.indexOf("chkBoxId") != -1 )
          {
           if(e.checked)
               {    
              //Your code goes here     
               }        
          } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: The name 'form1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: You have to give the id for form tage you have in your page. Find <Form tag in html of page and give its id. The second method does not need id of form you can use that also

Comment: With the second method, there is no more error. But, what's "chkBoxId" anyway? Because when I add a counter just to check the number of checkboxes I'm getting 0.

Comment: chkBoxId is id of the checkbox in the grid you are using for indication for deletion intention.

Comment: Thanks, I've just checked in the W3Schools and found out the meaning of the method. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

```
var inputs = lv.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
```